# Concatenation operator not allow in module instantiation

Tags: concatenation, verilog, bit

```
MUX32_16x1 inst9(muxR, dontNeed, addSub, AddSub, mult, shift, shift, wireAnd, wireOr, wireNor, {31{0}, addSub[31]}, dontNeed, dontNeed, dontNeed, dontNeed, dontNeed, dontNeed, OPRN[3:0]);
```

Above is my instantiation of a 16x1 mux, I'm trying to set one parameter to 0 for the first 31 bits leaving only the last bit as an input by doing this

```
{31{0}, addSub[31]}
```

I'm not sure why the program is giving out this error

```
near ",": syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting '}'.
```

is curly braces operator not allow in module instantiation?

sorry, I'm very new to Verilog programming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're doing repeated concatenation, you need to enclose it in another set of braces, so `{31{1'b0}}` is the same as `31'd0`.

Try:

```
{{31{1'b0}}, addSub[31]}
```

Or:

```
{31'd0, addSub[31]}
```